# TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new'

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib

I'm having a hard time trying to plot histograms using python, numpy and matplotlib on a mac osx. I had this working perfectly 6 months ago however the same code produces this error:

```
In [1]: %matplotlib inline

In [2]:import numpy as np
       from numpy.random import randn
       import pandas as pd
       import matplotlib as mpl
       import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
       from scipy import stats

       data = randn(75)
       plt.hist(data)
```

Returns the following message:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-2-fa104aadeee7> in <module>()
      8 
      9 data = randn(75)
---> 10 plt.hist(data,bins=20, density=True)

     /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/pyplot.pyc in hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom,  histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, hold, **kwargs)
   2339         ax.hold(hold)
   2340     try:
-> 2341         ret = ax.hist(x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative,  bottom,     histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, **kwargs)
   2342         draw_if_interactive()
   2343     finally:

/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib/axes.pyc in hist(self, x, bins, range, normed, weights, cumulative, bottom, histtype, align, orientation, rwidth, log, color, label, **kwargs)
   7734             # this will automatically overwrite bins,
   7735             # so that each histogram uses the same bins
-> 7736             m, bins = np.histogram(x[i], bins, weights=w[i],     **hist_kwargs)
   7737             if normed:
   7738                 db = np.diff(bins)

TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new''
```

I have attempted to uninstall and reinstall python, ipython, numpy, matplotlib and scipy and install them in `/usr/local/bin` though the error persists.

Has anyone seen this issue before or would know a possible solution? Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the *exact* code that produced the error? It seems that it happened on line 10, but your `In [2]` only has 9 lines (and other kwargs). And also can you try with just importing `plt` and `randn`?

Comment: The code in the traceback is different than the code you wrote above: `plt.hist(data,bins=20, density=True)` vs `plt.hist(data)`

Comment: Sorry, i did use `plt.hist(data,bins=20, density=True)` in the initial example then i removed it and got the terminals mixed up. the exact error occurs with both however. I still get `TypeError: histogram() got an unexpected keyword argument 'new''` for bboth

Comment: Doesn't happen when I run the code sample (Matplotlib version 1.4.3,
Numpy version 1.8.1,
Scipy version 0.15.1).

Answer (score 3):

For me the comment from cphlewis was the hint I needed. I was working with matplotlib 1.1, and after an update to 1.5 everything works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In OSX, I had to manually delete the matplotlib library: `rm -rf /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/matplotlib`

Then I uninstalled the matplotlib: `sudo pip uninstall matplotlib`
and I re-installed `matplotlib`: `sudo pip install matplotlib==1.5.1`

This seemed to work for me.